# How to display images on button action

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uibutton, uiimage

I have 10 `UIImages`. When I click the `UIButton` it displaying under `UIScrollView. But I need to implement the`UIButton`like **Next**, if`UIButton`is clicked first time, it displays the first`UIImage`, then after that, on click it displays next image. If I click the back button, the previous image should be displayed.

[image]

```
int   currentIndex = 0;
int MAX_COUNT;

NSMutableArray *imageName = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                                @"spices.jpg",
                                @"spice_powder.jpg", 
                                @"turmeric.jpg",
                                @"whynani_img3.jpg",
                                @"spice_blends.jpg",
                                @"products1.png", nil];

currentIndex = currentIndex + 1;
if(currentIndex > MAX_COUNT) {
   currentIndex = MAX_COUNT;
}        

for (int i = 0; i<[imageName count]; i++ ) {

   UIImageView  *mmageView = 
     [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200,200,350,350)];
   [mmageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[imageName objectAtIndex:i]]];            
   [self.view addSubview:mmageView];           
}
```

Comment: Just make the array of images and on click display according to their indexes.

Comment: @HimanshuJoshi: Can you help with my edited code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a global **imageView** and an `int` in interface file

```
UIImageView *imgView;
int index;
```

In `viewDidLoad:`

```
index = 0;

imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200,200,350,350)];
[imgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[imageName objectAtIndex:index]]];
[self.view addSubView:imgView];
```

In `Next Button Action`

```
-(void)nextButtonAction
{
  ++index;

  [previousBtn setEnabled:YES]; 

  if (index > [imageName count])
  {
    index = [imageName count] - 1;
    [nextBtn setEnabled:NO];
  }

  [imgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[imageName objectAtIndex:index]]];

}
```

In `Previous Button Action`

```
-(void)previousButtonAction
{
  --index;

  [nextBtn setEnabled:YES]; 

  if (index < 0)
  {
    index = 0;
    [previousBtn setEnabled:NO];
  }

  [imgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[imageName objectAtIndex:index]]];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the same using a UIViewController having 2 UIButtons with custom images depicting forward and back along with UIImageView. On selecting the next / back button load the appropriate image. The image name has to be stored in an NSArray.

Hope this helps.

Edit: sample code as given below,

In .h file

```
@property(nonatomic, weak) UIImageView *imageView;
@property(nonatomic, weak) UIButton *nextButton;
@property(nonatomic, weak) UIButton *backButton;

(IBAction)btnNextBtn:(id)sender;
(IBAction)btnBackBtn:(id)sender;
```

In .m file

```
(void)viewDidLoad {
    currentIndex = 0;
    NSMutableArray *imageName = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Myprofile.png", 
                                 @"great_ideas_wordle2.png", @"Review.png", 
                                 @"collaborate.png", nil];

   imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200,200,350,350)];
   [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[imageName objectAtIndex:currentIndex]]];
   [self.view addSubView:imageView];
}

(IBAction)btnNextBtn:(id)sender {
     currentIndex = currentIndex + 1;
     if(currentIndex > MAX_COUNT) {
         currentIndex = MAX_COUNT;
     }
     // load the image view with the currentIndex from the array.
     [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[imageName objectAtIndex:currentIndex]]];
}

(IBAction)btnBackBtn:(id)sender {
     currentIndex = currentIndex - 1;
     if (currentIndex < 0) {
         currentIndex = 0;
     }
     // load the image view with the currentIndex from the array.
     [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[imageName objectAtIndex:currentIndex]]];
}
```

Comment: In your for loop you are creating new imageview and adding it to UIView which is incorrect. You create your UIImageView and UIButton using storyboard. The same UIImageView should be used to display the images.

Comment: I didn't understand you logic. I'm creating UIImageView and button. I'm not using storyboard. without adding UIImageView to UIView then how it will displays?

Comment: Its incorrect. If you are using XIB then add these UIComponents and link your components to its respective variable name.

Comment: here what is error in my code. What can i do. Again telling i'm not using storyboard. what should i call herr // load the image view with the currentIndex from the array.

Comment: Are you using XIB or creating UIControls programatically? Please find my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

***write this in .h file***

```
@property (nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UIImageView *imageview1;

@property (nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UIButton *pre,*next;

@property (nonatomic,retain) NSArray *images;

@property (nonatomic) int currentindex;

-(IBAction)prebtn:(id)sender;

-(IBAction)nextbtn:(id)sender;
```

***write this code in .m file***

```
@implementation ViewController

@synthesize images;
@synthesize currentindex;
@synthesize pre,next;
@synthesize imageview1;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 [super viewDidLoad];
 // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

  self.currentindex = 0;

  self.images = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"images-2.jpeg",@"images-    3.jpeg",@"images.jpeg", nil];
 imageview1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"images-2.jpeg"];
 [pre setEnabled:NO];
  } 

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
  {
 [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(IBAction)nextbtn:(id)sender{
currentindex = currentindex + 1;
[pre setEnabled:YES];
if (currentindex >= [images count])
{
currentindex = currentindex - 1;
[next setEnabled:NO];
}
imageview1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[images objectAtIndex:currentindex]];    
}

-(IBAction)prebtn:(id)sender{

currentindex = currentindex - 1;
[next setEnabled:YES];
if(currentindex < 0)
{
currentindex = 0;
[pre setEnabled:NO];
}
imageview1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[images objectAtIndex:currentindex]];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code

.h file

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *imageView;
@property(nonatomic, strong) UIButton *nextButton;
@property(nonatomic, strong) UIButton *previousButton;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *imagesArrayName;
@property(nonatomic) int   currentIndex;

-(IBAction)btnNextImage:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)btnPreviousImage:(id)sender;
```

.m file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.currentIndex = 0;

    NSMutableArray *imagesArrayName = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                                      @"spices.jpg",
                                      @"spice_powder.jpg", 
                                      @"turmeric.jpg",
                                      @"whynani_img3.jpg",
                                      @"spice_blends.jpg",
                                      @"products1.png", nil];

    [self.nextButton addTarget:self action:@selector(btnNextImage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.previousButton addTarget:self action:@selector(btnPreviousImage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [self.imageView setImage[UIImage imageNamed:(NSString*)[imagesArrayName objectAtIndex:currenIndex]]];

    [self.previousButton setEnabled:FALSE];

}

-(IBAction)btnNextImage:(id)sender {

    self.currentIndex = self.currentIndex + 1;

    [self.imageView setImage[UIImage imageNamed:(NSString*)[imagesArrayName objectAtIndex:currenIndex]]];

    if (self.currentIndex == [self.imagesArrayName count] - 1) {

        [self.nextButton setEnabled:FALSE];
    }
    [self.previousButton setEnabled:TRUE];

}
-(IBAction)btnPreviousImage:(id)sender{

    self.currentIndex = self.currentIndex - 1;

    [self.imageView setImage[UIImage imageNamed:(NSString*)[imagesArrayName objectAtIndex:currenIndex]]];

    if (self.currentIndex == 0) {

        [self.previousButton setEnabled:FALSE];
    }
    [self.nextButton setEnabled:TRUE];
}
```